# TypeError: message.client.commands.get(...).execute is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'search',
    aliases: ['search'],
    description: 'Search and select videos to play.',
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        if (!args.length)
            return message.reply(`Usage: ${message.client.prefix}${module.exports.name} <Video Name>`).catch(console.error);
        if (message.channel.activeCollector)
            return message.reply("A message collector is already active in this channel.");
        if (!message.member.voice.channel)
            return message.reply("You need to join a voice channel first!").catch(console.error);

        const search = args.join(" ");

        let resultsEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`**Reply with the song number you want to play**`)
            .setDescription(`Results for: ${search}`)
            .setColor(COLORS.DARK_RED);

        try {
            const results = await youtube.searchVideos(search, 20);
            results.map((video, index) => resultsEmbed.addField(video.shortURL, `${index + 1}. ${video.title}`));

            var resultsMessage = await message.channel.send(resultsEmbed);

            function filter(msg) {
                const pattern = /(^[1-9][0-9]{0,1}$)/g;
                return pattern.test(msg.content) && parseInt(msg.content.match(pattern)[0]) <= 20;
            }

            message.channel.activeCollector = true;
            const response = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
                max: 1,
                time: 30000,
                errors: ["time"]
            });
            const choice = resultsEmbed.fields[parseInt(response.first()) - 1].name;

            message.channel.activeCollector = false;
            message.client.commands.get("play").execute(message, [choice]);
            resultsMessage.delete().catch(console.error);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            message.channel.activeCollector = false;
        }
    }
};
```

I have a problem with my code, when I run the code it throws me an embed with the song list, but when I choose the song, I get an error TypeError: message.client.commands.get(...).execute is not a function on line 49
Que debo de hacer para corregir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to get the bot client instead of the client who sent the message?

Try changing

```js
message.client.commands.get("play").execute(message, [choice]);
// to
client.commands.get("play").execute(message, [choice]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that "play" exists.

Perhaps you should check if play doesn't exist, handle that scenario.

```
if (message.client.commands.get("play") === undefined){
    ... do some logic
}
```

Comment: The play command already exists, I want to enter the number from the list, choose it, and play the song, something like this: play "#_song"